# Error running Snaps after system update throws 'multiple nvidia drivers detected, this is not supported' error

Tags: nvidia, snap

I have located where the error message originates from it is in https://github.com/snapcore/snap-confine/blob/master/src/mount-support-nvidia.c line number 221. As I have only a single nvidia driver installed I suspect it is is the same issue. I am not a developer but looking at the code preceding this line I can see the statement.

const char *glob_pattern = "/usr/lib/nvidia-[1-9][0-9][0-9]"

this will pick up nvidia-352/ nvidia-361/ and nvidia-361-prime/ ? on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

OK so have solved this it is the same as somebody else reported, but a bit more detail from me. in /usr/lib I have 2 folders with the pattern.

usr/lib/nvidia-[1-9][0-9][0-9]

in my case nvidia-361 and nvidia-352

The nvidia-352 folder just contains a couple of symbolic links
whereas the nvidia-361 folder contains all the driver software.

to check I renamed the nvidia-352 folder

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo mv nvidia-352 fred
```

then launched a snap

```
/snap/bin/libreoffice
```

This launched as normal

remember if this works to remove the folder completely

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo rm -fr fred
```

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I experienced the same problem.  There is a bug with a workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1616586